# How do I adjust my Flutter application after renaming User Directory on Windows?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I just renamed my User folder on windows and parts my project broke. Google SignIn stopped working and and Android Studio keeps throwing this error:

> √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
> W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 8230): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this
> is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
> Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49529/j_Bq7StHxxc=/ws
> Syncing files to device RMX2020...
> I/GED     ( 8230): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 24, oppidx_max 24,
> oppidx_min 0
> I/flutter ( 8230): connected
> Unhandled exception:
> Invalid argument(s): A directory corresponding to fileSystemPath
> "C:\Users\Admn\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\devtools-2.6.0\build" could not
> be found
> #0      createStaticHandler (package:shelf_static/src/static_handler.dart:50:5)
> #1      defaultHandler (package:devtools_server/src/external_handlers.dart:38:23)
>
> #2      serveDevTools (package:devtools_server/src/server.dart:201:15)
>
> #3      serveDevToolsWithArgs (package:devtools_server/src/server.dart:72:10)

This is my Flutter Doctor result:

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.631], locale
> en-US)
> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
> ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
> [√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
> [√] Connected device (3 available)
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Has anyone else faced this issue? Is there a file with a value I can adjust?

Comment: It looks like your flutter is ok. But you should accept those licenses. I think you just have to reopen the project. Maybe you should restart your IDE. Usually my VS Code is buggy.